# Javascript recursion to add the all the "total" properties up and return back to the user

Tags: javascript, recursion

I got the following data and I need to return the recursive total (in this case 60). Code below returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined` pointing to `object`. I think the code I'm using here is not for an array definition. How can I transform it to use arrays?

```
var data = [
    {
        total: 10,
        moreData: {
            total: 10
        }
    },
    {
        total: 10,
        moreData: {
            total: 10,
            moreData: {
                total: 10
            }
        }
    },
    {
        total: 10
    }
];

function sumUp(object){
    object.totalValue=0;
    for(child of object.children){
        object.totalValue+=sumUp(child);
    }
    return object.totalValue+object.value;
}

totalofall=sumUp(data);
console.log(totalofall);
```

Comment: where is the 'children' property of `data` defined? `children` is a property of nodes in the DOM, representing a collection of HTML element children of the node. It is not an accessor property of Object objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recursive way along with `array.prototype.map` and `array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
var data = [
    {
        total: 10,
        moreData: {
            total: 10
        }
    },
    {
        total: 10,
        moreData: {
            total: 10,
            moreData: {
                total: 10
            }
        }
    },
    {
        total: 10
    }
];

var sum = data.map(totInObj).reduce((m, o) => m + o, 0);
console.log(sum);

function totInObj(obj) {
    return obj.moreData ? obj.total + totInObj(obj.moreData) : obj.total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your recursive method.

```
function sumUp(obj){
    totalofall +=obj.total;
    if(obj.moreData != undefined)
    {
        sumUp(obj.moreData);
    }
}
```

There is no `object.children` property for `data`.  `data` is a array and you can iterate it with the recursive function.

```
for(obj of data){
    sumUp(obj);
}
```

Finally, complete code looks like.

```js
var data = [
    {
        total: 10,
        moreData: {
            total: 10
        }
    },
    {
        total: 10,
        moreData: {
            total: 10,
            moreData: {
                total: 10
            }
        }
    },
    {
        total: 10
    }
];
var totalofall = 0;
function sumUp(obj){
    totalofall +=obj.total;
 if(obj.moreData != undefined)
 {
  sumUp(obj.moreData);
 }
}
for(obj of data){
 sumUp(obj);
}

console.log(totalofall);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle array items and sum of `total`s rather than `value` (**explanation inline**)

```
function sumUp(object)
{
    var totalValue=0; //keep a local variable instead of assigning a new property to object
    if ( Array.isArray( object ) ) //if object is an array, iterate the same
    {
       object.forEach( s => ( totalValue += sumUp( s ) ) );
    }
    if ( object.moreData ) //check for moreData instead of children
    {
       totalValue += sumUp( object.moreData );
    }
    return totalValue + (object.total || 0); //sum of total instead of value
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var data = [
    {
        total: 10,
        moreData: {
            total: 10
        }
    },
    {
        total: 10,
        moreData: {
            total: 10,
            moreData: {
                total: 10
            }
        }
    },
    {
        total: 10
    }
];

function sumUp(object)
{
    var totalValue = 0; 
    if ( Array.isArray( object ) )
    {
       object.forEach( s => ( totalValue += sumUp( s ) ) );
    }
    if ( object.moreData )
    {
       totalValue += sumUp( object.moreData );
    }
    return totalValue + (object.total || 0);
}

console.log( sumUp( data ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest seems to be to traverse the array, then going deep into the objects:

```
 let result = 0;

 for(let obj of data){
   do {
     result += obj.total;
   } while(obj = obj.moreData);
}
```